# PayPal not working in the Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center

PayPal ist not working for me on Ubuntu 12.10 in the Ubuntu Software Center (USC) any more. I bought a lot of stuff via PayPal on the USC but now it stops working:

After the "Log in to your PayPal account to complete this purchase" dialog appears and clicking on the "Log in" button, the dialog with the text "Please continue your purchase in the secure window we opened. If you don't see it, click the button below" appears. If I click on the "Go" button, nothing happens.

Any ideas? Is this a bug?

Comment: I entered a bug report on Launchpad.net: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1165140

Comment: The bug link changed to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1164036

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue cause by a change in webkit preventing popups our team is actively trying to resolve this issue, if you could please bear with us it isn't a trivial fix.

Comment: It seems to be fixed! I was able to buy something in the USC!

Comment: Yeap it took us a couple of week to re-engineer it but it should be fine now

Comment: @Davmor2 If it's been fixed how come the bug hasn't been resolved?